# Trouble uploading folder/files to a server using vinyl-ftp and Gulp

Tags: ftp, gulp

I have two variables.

```
var files = 'dist/**';
var destination = '/public_html/projects/test';
```

Using Gulp, my tasks add files to the dist folder when they are production ready.

Then using vinyl-ftp, an npm package, I upload the `files` variable to `destination` on the server.

My problem is that when the files are uploaded, my dist folder is uploaded as well. The path then looks like this to my index: `public_html/projects/test/dist/index.html`.

My question then is how do I only grab the conents of `dist` and then upload those to the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your gulp.src base path to your local 'dist' subfolder. e.g.

```
gulp
 .src('dist/**', {base: 'dist/'})
 .pipe(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

In my Case the solution given by user15895 works fine, Thank you!!! But I need do a simple ajdust.

```
var  ftp  = require('vinyl-ftp'),
gutil = require('gulp-util');

//Here in my gulp deploy task .. 
var ftpConnection = ftp.create({
  host     : "ftp.xxx.com",
  user     : "xxx",
  password : "xxx",
  parallel : 10,
  log      : gutil.log
});

var globs = [ './build/**'];

return gulp.src( globs, {base : './build' , buffer : false })
      .pipe( ftpConnection.newer('/public_html'))
      .pipe( ftpConnection.dest('/public_html'))
```